# Can I rely on the compiler finding and optimizing simple boolean loop invariants?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

I have a loop like the one below which has an invariant, here the never changing value of `scaleEveryValueByTwo`. **Can I rely on the compiler finding this invariant and not checking the condition in every iteration** (essentially compiling to something anologous to the code at the bottom)?

```
void loadValuesFromDisk(const bool scaleEveryValueByTwo)
{
    std::vector<MyValueType> xs;
    while(fileHasNewValues())
    {
        auto x = loadNextValue();
        if (scaleEveryValueByTwo)
        {
            x *= 2;
        }
        xs.push_back(x);
    }
}
```

I can of course split this into two loops manually (see below) or put the scaling part in a separate function, but in many cases this makes the code much longer and in my opinion harder to read (for example if I have nested loops for all dimensions of 3D data I would duplicate all three lines of loop headers and up to six lines of curly braces).

```
void loadValuesFromDisk(const bool scaleEveryValueByTwo)
{
    std::vector<MyValueType> xs;
    while(fileHasNewValues())
    {
        auto x = loadNextValue();
        xs.push_back(x);
    }

    if (scaleEveryValueByTwo)
    {
        for(auto &x : xs)
        {
            x *= 2;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm primarily interested if I can rely on this (or even better, enforce) this optimization for commonly used compilers like gcc or MSVC, not some exotic ones that might be missing optimization that are de facto standard in most compilers.

Comment: More than likely it will.  Even if it doesn't the branch predictor will learn it quickly and the performance will be the same.

Comment: The general rule of thumb is that compiler will make make all optimizations you can think about and a bunch of other that you didn't even expect.

Comment: @NathanOliver is correct... The compiler will very likely perform this optimization _if it is a good idea_. Asking this sort of question outside the context of a profiling result is almost certainly premature optimization (i.e. the wrong question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier there used to be /Og (global optimization) in MSVC compiler, which are now enabled by default. 
My guess is other compilers also do that.

To know how the loop optimization is done, look into below link and search for "Loop optimization"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/og-global-optimizations?view=vs-2019

As this comes by default now, you can rely on compiler.

Comment: This brought me on the right track, other compilers seem to have similar options, e.g. `-fmove-loop-invariants` and a few more aggressive ones for [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can make `scaleEveryValueByTwo` a template parameter to be sure that the condition is evaluated only once.
In C++17 you can use `if constexpr` as follows

```
template <bool scaleEveryValueByTwo>
void loadValuesFromDisk()
{
    std::vector<MyValueType> xs;
    while(fileHasNewValues())
    {
        auto x = loadNextValue();
        if constexpr (scaleEveryValueByTwo)
        {
            x *= 2;
        }
        xs.push_back(x);
    }
}
```

If you do not have yet C++17 the code above can be obtained, for example, by involving an auxiliary template function `multiply` as follows

```
template <bool activate>
void multiply(decltype(loadNextValue())& x);

template <>
void multiply<true>(decltype(loadNextValue())& x) { x *= 2; }

template <>
void multiply<false>(decltype(loadNextValue())& x) { }

template <bool scaleEveryValueByTwo>
void loadValuesFromDisk()
{
    std::vector<MyValueType> xs;
    while(fileHasNewValues())
    {
        auto x = loadNextValue();
        multiply<scaleEveryValueByTwo>(x);
        xs.push_back(x);
    }
}
```

(Note: I am using `decltype` because I do not know what your routine `loadNextValue()` returns.)

Then you call either `loadValuesFromDisk<true>()` or `loadValuesFromDisk<false>()`. If `scaleEveryValueByTwo` is only known at runtime, you can branch to the appropriate function:

```
void loadValuesFromDisk(bool const scaleEveryValueByTwo)
{
    if (scaleEveryValueByTwo)
        loadValuesFromDisk<true>();
    else
        loadValuesFromDisk<false>();
}
```

Comment: The `if constexpr` is not needed for the prior-to-C++17 case. `if (/* pure constexpr constant */) {` will definitely be optimized away by the compiler.